# Ignore Test or TestFixture based on a condition

Tags: nunit

We've got some integration tests in our solution. To run these tests, simulation software must be installed on the developer PC. This software is, however, not installed on every developer PC. If the simulation software is not installed, these tests should be skipped, otherwise ==> NullRefException.

I'm now seeking for a way to do a "conditional ignore" for tests/testfixtures.

Something like

```
if(simulationFilesExist)
  do testfixture
else 
  skip testfixture
```

NUnit gives some useful things like ignore and explicit, but that's not quite what I need.

Answer (score 59):

Use some code in your test or fixture set up method that detects if the simulation software is installed or not and calls [Assert.Ignore()](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5.2) if it isn't.

```cs
[SetUp]
public void TestSetUp() 
{
     if (!TestHelper.SimulationFilesExist())
     {
         Assert.Ignore( "Simulation files are not installed.  Omitting." );
     }
}
```

or

```cs
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void FixtureSetUp()
{
     if (!TestHelper.SimulationFilesExist())
     {
         Assert.Ignore( "Simulation files are not installed.  Omitting fixture." );
     }
}
```

In [NUnit 3.0](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureSetUp-Attribute) and higher you have to use `OneTimeSetUp` attribute instead of `TestFixtureSetUp`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But this will result in a failed test, not really what I want. The fact that test did not executed does not mean it should indicate failed (in my case).

Comment: No.  Assert.Fail will result in a failed test.  Assert.Ignore() does exactly what you want it to do.  It causes the test to be ignored at runtime.  Quoting from the docs: "The Assert.Ignore method provides you with the ability to dynamically cause a test or suite to be ignored at runtime."

Comment: You're right tvanfosson. When you only run the testfixture it will indicate failed, but when you run a bunch of testfixtures all together the testfixture will be omitted and the end result is SUCCESS!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depending on which version of the NUnit framework you're using, there is also Assert.Inconclusive. This will also result in a successful result, but flag that those tests may fail under other conditions.

Answer (score 8):

NUnit also gives you the option to supply a Category attribute.

Depending on how you are launching your tests, it may be appropriate to flag all the tests that require the simulator with a known category (e.g., *[Category("RequiresSimulationSoftware")]*). Then from the NUnit GUI you can choose to exclude certain categories. You can do the same thing from the NUnit command line runner (specify */exclude:RequiresSimulationSoftware* if applicable).

Comment: Hey, I thought of this solution. The downside of this solution is that it is caller specific. We sometimes execute the tests from within VStudio and the other time from a script. Both should be altered and maintained.

Comment: +1. I like it much more than "Assert.Ignore", because it's just attribute and additional flag to CLI in my case.

Comment: I don't think this helps the solution. Because runtime based on the availability of values (input) the output of test varies. This gives the correct measure of your tests. Whereas Category cannot be changed during runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to duplicate `Assert.Ignore` condition in every test case, so I ended up using a custom `Attribute` class, which I derived from the `NUnitAttribute` class:

```csharp
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class SimulatorOnlyAttribute : NUnitAttribute, IApplyToTest
{
    public void ApplyToTest(Test test)
    {
        if (test.RunState == RunState.NotRunnable)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!Helper.RunsOnSimulator)
        {
            test.RunState = RunState.Ignored;
            test.Properties.Set(PropertyNames.SkipReason, "This test should run only on simulator");
        }
    }
}
```

So now I can just mark required test cases with the new attribute:

```csharp
[SimulatorOnly]
public void Test()
```

For reference you could investigate source code of the [`IgnoreAttribute`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/IgnoreAttribute.cs).

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```csharp
[SetUp]
public void TestSetUp()
{
     if (!TestHelper.SimulationFilesExist())
     {
         Assert.Ignore( "Simulation files are not installed.  Omitting." );
     }
}
```

You use this type of condition in `TestFixtureSet Attribute`. But if this fixture have a parameterized test then if you want to ignore parameterized test of this fixture then this goes in an infinite loop and your test will be hanged. So you use the setup attribute better for the *if* condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to alter the result status of a test.  Here are a few, and ways to read out the various status:

```csharp
TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.MakeInvalid("I want this test to be SKIPPED");

ResultState resultStateObject = new ResultState(TestStatus.Skipped);
TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult.SetResult(resultStateObject, "this test is being skipped derp derp");
TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.RunState = RunState.Ignored;
Logger.log("After doing things");

resultstate = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult.ResultState.ToString();
Logger.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Result State: " + resultstate);

resultstatestatus = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult.ResultState.Status.ToString();
Logger.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Result State Status: " + resultstate);

runstate = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.RunState.ToString();
Logger.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Run State: " + runstate); //test="@runstate = 'Skipped' or @runstate = 'Ignored' or @runstate='Inconclusive'

status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString();
Logger.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Result Status: " + status);

message = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult.Message.ToString();
Logger.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Message: " + message);
```