# How to ignore some tests on appharbor deploy

Tags: nunit, continuous-integration, appharbor

AppHarbor automatically runs your unit test when they build your app.  I'd like to have AppHarbor ignore a certain "Category" of tests, specifically, those that test persistance configuration.

So, I've add the following attribute to the test class I want ignored

```
[TestFixture(Category = "Database")]
```

How do I tell AppHarbor to not run those tests?

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some resources that'll let you accomplish this:

- [Ignore Test or TestFixture based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594293/ignore-test-or-testfixture-based-on-condition)
- [Ignoring a unit test project](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1481-ignoring-a-unit-test-project)
- [Can AppHarbor set a conditional compilation symbol during build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389673/can-appharbor-set-a-conditional-compilation-symbol-during-build)